# Find the empty array

Tags: objective-c, xcode, arrays

Is there some method to understand what of my 20 Arrays is empty when I get this problem?

```
2012-12-06 16:52:05.409 Posizione Corrente 3[3738:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught     exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds   for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x383042a3 0x34adb97f 0x3824fb75 0x560ab 0x38a49545 0x38a2e30b 0x38a457c7 0x38a01803 0x3bed7d63 0x3bed7901 0x3bed8835 0x3bed821b 0x3bed8029 0x3bed7e89 0x382d96cd 0x382d79c1  0x382d7d17 0x3824aebd 0x3824ad49 0x340232eb 0x38a522f9 0x7c675 0x3940bb20)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set a breakpoint on Objective-C exceptions using Xcode's Breakpoint Navigator, the program should stop when it encounters that error and show you the code that caused it.  From the line of code, it should be reasonably easy to see which array is implicated.

Comment: so no methods to find directly this array?

Comment: I suppose you could write a method like `- (id)objectFromValidArray:(NSArray *)array atIndex:(NSUInteger)offset;` that would check the array's validity and call it every time instead of `objectAtIndex:` but it seems like a lot of effort compared to fixing the bug.

Answer (score 0):

You can check with the following code, if you array contains any value or not.

```
if([myArray count]==0){
    //do this
}
else{
   //do you array manipulation
}
```

Comment: yes but I can't check every array! I've more the 20 arrays. Anyway thanks

Comment: Or you can subclass or write a category that will send you a notification...for each and every class. This can be a POC. am not sure...That is why i am writing it here not in my answer.